# can we calculate the popularity of our site with unique browser(UN)? How we will get it?

Tags: web, analytics, popularity

I found some website is publishing thy have xxx number if unique browser and that is more that so and so website

can we calculate the site popularity on the basis of Unique Browser(UB) like Unique visitor?

Answer (score 0):

Many places I've seen tend to use (a more or less correctly calculated version of) [unique user or unique visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_user) as the measurement.

It's a measurement defined by [IFABC Global Web Standards](http://www.ifabc.org/resources/metrics/website-metrics/ifabc-www-standards-group) (ie measured in more or less the same way everywhere), so it's comparable between sites. It combines IP address with (usually) a tracking cookie to track unique users.

Some web sites instead use IP combined with [browser fingerprinting](https://panopticlick.eff.org/browser-uniqueness.pdf), which does not require a tracking cookie to be set.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found http://www.effectivemeasure.com/ this web site is providing the measurement like google analytics